# Redundant power supply

Tags: power-supply-unit

I have been hit by my inexperience with power supplies... I bought a Ablecom (SuperMicro) PWS-801-1R redundant power supply. But this is in fact a module, that is not redundant in itself, and must be plugged into ... don't know what ???
So my question is : what is needed to assemble a redundant power supply for a 3U rack, idealy from a PWS-801-1S part ?
Is there any standard ?

Comment: I've given you an answer, though I don't know how good it is since I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. I can tell you for sure that the power supply you purchased must be plugged in to a server (MealstroM listed compatible models), but that's only part of the story...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking, so I'll answer the two questions I *think* you're asking -- let me know if I'm off base:

**Q1: What is required to provide redundant power to a server?**
You need the following:

1. A server that supports redundant power supplies.
2. compatible power supply modules.
3. Two separate sources of power (different circuits/UPS feeds/etc. that are reasonably independent)

---

**Q2: What is required to provide redundant power to a whole rack?**
Way more than just redundant power supplies in the server.  You will need, at a minimum:

1. Two independent sources of power
   (This can be as simple as separate breakers, or infinitely more complex: 2 UPS systems, multiple utility feeds, utility + full-time generator, etc.)
2. Redundant power distribution
   (either a "dual-infeed" CDU or two CDUs/power strips - connected to the 2 sources in (1) via separate circuits)
3. Redundant power supplies in all servers
   (One PSU connected to each distribution unit in (2))

---

In power, as in all things, true redundancy is expensive.

Comment: My question was about the inside of the server. I have a chassis, and I want to replace the original power supply (600W non redundant) with a redundant 800W power supply. I bought the PWS-801-1R from a web site, but it seems it can not work on its own, it needs to be plugged into something... I'm looking for that something...

Comment: @alci That "something" is a **compatible** server chassis - See MealstroM's answer for a list of them. The device you purchased is a single module: You put two of them into a *compatible* server chassis to provide redundant power.  With this power supply, If you have a compatible server chassis it should literally just slide in to a space in the back of the machine * lock in to place.

Comment: So no way to buy the spare part that makes the chassis compatible, however this spare part is called ? Because I already have the chassis, it has a 600W power supply that can be removed, and I wanted to replace this power supply with a redundant one...

Answer (score 2):

> Compatibility for PWS-801-1R

```
* Supermicro A+ Server 4021M-32R
* Supermicro A+ Server 4021M-T2R+
* Supermicro A+ Server 4021M-82R+
```

Answer (score 0):

Supermicro lists them on their store site under 'Server Accessories' and then 'Power Distributors'

I believe this is exactly the piece you were looking for; because it took me ages to find them without being only included in a chassis / etc.

As far as which power supply modules are compatible with which Power Distributors; I have yet to find an effective method.